# JDO Query returns zero results

Tags: gwt, jdo

I am building a GWT app to access a list of houses persisted using JDO on the server side.  The list of houses are then moved to the client side via an RPC "getHouseService" to be displayed and manipulated.  They don't get returned and saved on the server side afterwards.

When I run the app and execute the RPC service, the client always gets an empty list.
During testing, I note that my ide (eclipse) in debug mode notes the value of the returned list in getHouse is a StreamingQueryResult.

What am I doing wrong??  I've been stuck on this problem for over a week, and I can't find a related solution online.

This is the code I wrote to work with my data persistence:

```java
public static PersistenceManagerFactory getPersistenceManagerFactory() {
        return pmfInstance;
    }

    public void addHouse(List<House> listofHouses) {
        PersistenceManager pm = getPersistenceManagerFactory().getPersistenceManager(); 
        try {
            pm.makePersistentAll(listofHouses);
            System.out.println("after makePersistentAll");
        }
        finally {
            pm.close();
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<House> getHouses() {
        PersistenceManager pm = getPersistenceManagerFactory().getPersistenceManager();
    List<House> houseList = (List<House>) pm.newQuery("select from " + House.class.getName()).execute();
    return houseList;
    }
```

The House class is:

```java
package vancouverHEA.shared;

import javax.jdo.annotations.IdGeneratorStrategy;
import javax.jdo.annotations.IdentityType;
import javax.jdo.annotations.PersistenceCapable;
import javax.jdo.annotations.Persistent;
import javax.jdo.annotations.PrimaryKey;

import org.datanucleus.jpa.annotations.Extension;

import com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.IsSerializable;

@PersistenceCapable(identityType = IdentityType.APPLICATION, detachable = "true")
public class House extends Building implements IsSerializable {

    @PrimaryKey
    @Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
    @Extension(vendorName = "datanucleus", key = "gae.encoded-pk", value = "true")
    private Long key;
    @Persistent (serialized = "true")
    java.lang.Double landPrice;
    @Persistent (serialized = "true")
    java.lang.Double housePrice;
    @Persistent (serialized = "true")
    java.lang.Boolean forSale;
    @Persistent (serialized = "true")
    private java.lang.String realtorContact;
    @Persistent (serialized = "true")
    private java.lang.Integer listPrice;
    @Persistent (serialized = "true")
    private java.lang.Integer yrBuilt;
    @Persistent (serialized = "true")
    private java.lang.Integer yrReno;
    @Persistent (serialized = "true")
    private java.lang.String postalCode;
    @Persistent (serialized = "true")
    java.lang.Double latitude;
    @Persistent (serialized = "true")
    java.lang.Double longitude;

    String STRATA = "Strata";
    String SINGLE = "Single House" ;


    public House(double landPrice, double improvPrice, String address,
            String postalCode, int yrBuilt, int yrReno) {
        super();
        this.landPrice = landPrice;
        this.housePrice = improvPrice;
        this.address = address;
        this.postalCode = postalCode.trim().toUpperCase();
        this.yrBuilt = yrBuilt;
        this.yrReno = yrReno;
    }


    public String getPostalCode() {
        return postalCode;
    }


    public void setPostalCode(String postalCode) {
        this.postalCode = postalCode.trim().toUpperCase();
    }


    public double getLatitude() {
        return latitude;
    }


    public void setLatitude(double latitude) {
        this.latitude = latitude;
    }


    public double getLongitude() {
        return longitude;
    }


    public void setLongitude(double longitude) {
        this.longitude = longitude;
    }



    public double getPrice() {
        return this.landPrice + this.housePrice;
    }

    public boolean isForSale() {
        return forSale;
    }


    public void setForSale(boolean forSale) {
        this.forSale = forSale;
    }


    public String getRealtorContact() {
        return realtorContact;
    }


    public void setRealtorContact(String realtorContact) {
        this.realtorContact = realtorContact;
    }


    public int getListPrice() {
        return listPrice;
    }


    public void setListPrice(int listPrice) {
        this.listPrice = listPrice;
    }


    public int getYrBuilt() {
        return yrBuilt;
    }


    public void setYrBuilt(int yrBuilt) {
        this.yrBuilt = yrBuilt;
    }


    public int getYrReno() {
        return yrReno;
    }


    public void setYrReno(int yrReno) {
        this.yrReno = yrReno;
    }


    public void setLandPrice(Double landPrice) {
        this.landPrice = landPrice;
    }

    public double getLandPrice(){
        return landPrice;
    }

    public void setHousePrice(Double housePrice) {
        this.housePrice = housePrice;
    }

    public double getHousePrice() {
        return housePrice;
    }

}
```

Comment: Why would you serialise fields of type Double, String, Boolean, Integer? hence they are not usable in queries. Obviously the log tells you all that is happening, so would be best to inspect it

Answer (score 0):

This could be the same problem as described in this question: [GWT retrieve list from datastore via serviceimpl](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7641319/66416) To summarize the list is loaded lazy, so if you return the list via RPC it's not yet read and returns an empty list. The answer on the question https://stackoverflow.com/a/7646549/66416 suggest to call `size()` on the list before returning it, this will trigger the list to be read (although not sure if this is the most elegant solution).